How to implement react window in Shadcnui combobox?
I have very large lists of items that I need to show on the ui inside a Combobox of shadcn ui but due to lists being large, it takes too much time.
So I wanted to virtualize the list and only render the items on dom that are in the view.
I tried implementing react window and while it works, when I search something in the search box, the scroll doesn't work
type ComboboxItem = {
  value: string;
  label: string;
};

interface MultiselectComboboxProps {
  items: ComboboxItem[];
  placeholder?: string;
  selectedValues: string[];
  onValueChange: (values: string[]) => void;
  width?: string;
  showSearch?: boolean;
}

export function MultiselectCombobox({
  items,
  placeholder = "Select options...",
  selectedValues,
  onValueChange,
  width = "200px", 
  showSearch = true, 
}: MultiselectComboboxProps) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const [filteredOptions, setFilteredOptions] =
    React.useState<ComboboxItem[]>(items);

  const [tempSelectedValues, setTempSelectedValues] =
    React.useState<string[]>(selectedValues);

  const allSelected = tempSelectedValues.length === items.length;

  // Toggle selection for individual items
  const toggleSelection = (value: string) => {
    setTempSelectedValues(
      (prev) =>
        prev.includes(value)
          ? prev.filter((v) => v !== value) // Remove if already selected
          : [...prev, value] // Add if not selected
    );
  };

  // Toggle "Select All" option
  const toggleSelectAll = () => {
    setTempSelectedValues(
      allSelected ? [] : filteredOptions.map((item) => item.value)
    );
  };

  const handleSearch = (search: string) => {
    if (search.length) {
      const filteredItems = items.filter((item) =>
        item.value.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      );

      setFilteredOptions(filteredItems);
    } else {
      setFilteredOptions(items);
    }
  };

  const Row = ({
    index,
    style,
  }: {
    index: number;
    style: React.CSSProperties;
  }) => {
    const item = filteredOptions[index];
    const isChecked = tempSelectedValues.includes(item.value);

    return (
      <div style={style}>
        <CommandItem
          key={item.value}
          value={item.value}
          onSelect={() => toggleSelection(item.value)}>
          <Checkbox checked={isChecked} />
          <span
            style={{
              display: "inline-block",
              maxWidth: "calc(100% - 40px)", // Adjust for checkbox and padding
              whiteSpace: "nowrap",
              overflow: "hidden",
              textOverflow: "ellipsis",
            }}
            title={item.label} // Tooltip to show the full label
          >
            {item.label}
          </span>
        </CommandItem>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Popover modal={true} open={open} onOpenChange={handlePopoverClose}>
      <PopoverTrigger asChild>
        <Button
          variant="outline"
          role="combobox"
          aria-expanded={open}
          className={cn(
            "justify-between text-small font-normal",
            width && `w-[${width}]`
          )}
        >
          {tempSelectedValues.length > 0
            ? `${tempSelectedValues.length} out of ${items.length} selected`
            : placeholder}
          <ChevronsUpDown className="ml-2 h-4 w-4 shrink-0 opacity-50" />
        </Button>
      </PopoverTrigger>
      <PopoverContent className={`p-0 w-[--radix-popover-trigger-width]`}>
        <Command>
          {showSearch && (
            <CommandInput
              onValueChange={handleSearch}
              placeholder={`Search ${placeholder.toLowerCase()}`}
            />
          )}
          <CommandList>
            <CommandEmpty>No options found.</CommandEmpty>
            {filteredOptions.length ? (
              <div
                className="sticky top-0 bg-white z-10 font-bold flex gap-2 h-[26px] items-center mx-3 my-0 pt-[6px] text-sm"
                onClick={toggleSelectAll}>
                <Checkbox checked={allSelected} />
                Select all
              </div>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}

            <CommandGroup>
              <div className="max-h-[200px] overflow-y-auto">
                <List
                  height={200} // Visible height of the list
                  itemCount={filteredOptions.length} // Total number of items
                  itemSize={32} // Height of each row in px
                  width="100%" // Full width
                  itemData={filteredOptions}>
                  {Row}
                </List>
              </div>
            </CommandGroup>
          </CommandList>

          <div className="p-2 border-t flex justify-end gap-2">
            <Button
              variant="outline"
              size="sm"
              onClick={() => {
                setTempSelectedValues(selectedValues); // Reset state on Cancel
                setOpen(false);
              }}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button size="sm" onClick={applySelection}>
              Apply
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Command>
      </PopoverContent>
    </Popover>
  );
}


What mistake am I making in here? I am filtering the list on the basis of the search input and the list is being filtered. But then the scroll stops working.
